# How to determine whether a GIF image contains a graphic control extension

Tags: gif

The [1990 CompuServe GIF89a specification](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) defines a "graphic control extension" like so:

> The Graphic Control Extension contains parameters used
>   when processing a graphic rendering block. The scope of this extension is
>   the first graphic rendering block to follow. The extension contains only
>   one data sub-block.
>
> This block is OPTIONAL; at most one Graphic Control Extension may precede
>   a graphic rendering block. This is the only limit to the number of
>   Graphic Control Extensions that may be contained in a Data Stream.

As this is block optional, how does one determine whether or not an arbitrary GIF image contains a graphics control extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the specification pretty plainly states that *all* extensions, including the Graphic Control, Plain Text, Comment, and Application extensions, are demarcated by the presence of a `0x21` at the start of the block.

What threw me off is that GIFs contain a flag located in the Logical Screen Descriptor that denotes the presence of an optional Global Color Table block, but there is no such flag to denote the presence of a graphic control extension (not sure why).  It either comes right after the Logical Screen Descriptor or it doesn't.  Hope this helps someone down the road...